# Bash - match line if number is within a range defined in the line

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, grep

I have a text file with the following format:

```
Item A,10-20
Item B,21-30
Item C,31-60
Item D,61-120
```

how can I search the file with any number and I get the line returned that includes the number given by the range in the second field.

so lets say I search for `33` I get `Item C`
if I search for `100` I get `Item D` and so on...

(my question does not focus on the field separation but rather on matching the line within the range, so if I would get the whole line displayed this would be fine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shorter awk:

```
$ awk -F'[,-]' -v s=11 's>=$2 && s<=$3' file1
Item A,10-20

$ awk -F'[,-]' -v s=100 's>=$2 && s<=$3' file1
Item D,61-120

$ awk -F'[,-]' -v s=61 's>=$2 && s<=$3' file1
Item D,61-120
```

As mentioned in comments if you want to print only the labels just add `{print $1}` in the end:

```
$ awk -F'[,-]' -v s=61 's>=$2 && s<=$3{print $1}' file1
Item D
```

Comment: ok, you convinced me with the shortness :-)

Comment: Ah, I forgot `awk` can use a regex as a field separator. You could still add `{ print $1}` to just print the label.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
$ awk -vval=33  -F, '{ label = $1; split($2, limits, "-"); } 
                     limits[1]+0 <= val && val <= limits[2]+0 {print label} ' < input
Item C
```

We just split on `,` to separate the label, then split on `-` to separate the low and high limits. `+0` to force comparison as numbers.